# How i can audit AWS iam Users and Associated access keys for multiple AWS account using boto3

Tags: python, boto3, export-to-csv, amazon-iam

I  have script to list AWS IAM users and associated Access keys ,when key last used . I am not sure how my script can work for multiple profiles/aws accounts . I also need to export output on CSV file

Comment: What is the script? What is wrong with it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='IAM')

resource = boto3.resource('iam')

client = boto3.client("iam")

KEY = 'LastUsedDate'

for user in resource.users.all():

    Metadata = client.list_access_keys(UserName=user.user_name)

    if Metadata['AccessKeyMetadata'] :
        for key in user.access_keys.all():
            AccessId = key.access_key_id
            Status = key.status
            LastUsed = client.get_access_key_last_used(AccessKeyId=AccessId)
            if (Status == "Active"):
                if KEY in LastUsed['AccessKeyLastUsed']:
                    print ("User: " , user.user_name ,  "Key: " , AccessId , "AK Last Used: " , LastUsed['AccessKeyLastUsed'][KEY])
                else:
                    print ("User: ", user.user_name  , "Key: ",  AccessId , "Key is Active but NEVER USED")
            else:
                print ("User: ", user.user_name  , "Key: ",  AccessId , "Keys is InActive")
    else:
        print ("User: ", user.user_name  , "No KEYS found")
```